D365 Create multiple new ECO products
I need to create multiple products in an ECO header using OData. These products should appear with ChangeType "New" and Impact "New product". Using the UI that is possible without any problem. You can just click on "New" and select "Create new product". After that a window appears (that looks like the one for creating an engineering product), you fill in the data and the entry will be created for you.
This is my request for creating a new product using OData resources:
POST https://{{d365_url}}/data/EngineeringChangeOrderProductsV3
{
    "dataAreaId": "demf",
    "EngineeringChangeOrderNumber": "TestEco",
    "LineNumber": 2.0,
    "EngineeringProductCategoryDetailsName": "Test",
    "EngineeringChangeImpactType": "NewProduct",
    "ProductName": "CreatedUsingOData",
    "ProductSearchName": "EcoProduct",
    "NewProductVersionId": "V-01",
    "NewItemNumber": "220",
    "BOMUnitSymbol": "pcs"
}


You can already see a difference between the two created products. The one created with OData is missing the Item number. The defined "NewItemNumber": "220" is present in the product details.
Now I want to create another product (ChangeType: New, Impact: New product) and I am using the request shown below:
POST https://{{d365_url}}/data/EngineeringChangeOrderProductsV3
{
    "dataAreaId": "demf",
    "EngineeringChangeOrderNumber": "TestEco",
    "LineNumber": 3.0,
    "EngineeringProductCategoryDetailsName": "Test",
    "EngineeringChangeImpactType": "NewProduct",
    "ProductName": "CreatedUsingOData2",
    "ProductSearchName": "EcoProduct",
    "NewProductVersionId": "V-01",
    "NewItemNumber": "230",
    "BOMUnitSymbol": "pcs"
}

This will result in a 400 HTTP error response with this message:
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "An error has occurred.",
        "innererror": {
            "message": "Write failed for table row of type 'EngChgEngineeringChangeOrderProductV3Entity'. Infolog: Warning: New product  exists in the engineering change order TestEco and cannot be added.; Warning: The new product number  is already reserved in engineering change order TestEco; Warning: validateWrite failed on data source 'EngChgEcmProduct (EngChgEcmProduct)'.",
            "type": "Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.AxODataWriteException",
            "stacktrace": "   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.UpdateProcessor.CreateEntity_Save(ChangeOperationContext context, ChangeInfo changeInfo)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.ChangeInfo.ExecuteActionsInCompanyContext(IEnumerable`1 actionList, ChangeOperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.ChangeInfo.TrySave(ChangeOperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.Update.UpdateManager.SaveChanges()\r\n   at Microsoft.Dynamics.Platform.Integration.Services.OData.AxODataDelegatingHandler.<SaveChangesAsync>d__2.MoveNext()"
        }
    }
}

From the error message I found out that there is a number reserved for new products. So it is not possible to add more than one (newly created) product in any ECO unless the one is processed (I guess).
Am I missing something here? Maybe it is just a setting I need to change?
I have already tried:

Adding "CurrentItemNumber" to my request: Result --> D365FO thinks I try to add an existing one. Error Message: There is no product with that item number.
Creating a new EngineeringProduct and adding it to the ECO: Result --> The change type is automatically set the "Changed" and I am in fact generating a new item number.

